# Removing entries from a table where two instances occur

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2010 DB which assigns each product a unique stock number.
There is a separate entry for when the product is purchased, and then again when it is sold.
I am trying to find a way to write a query that will remove all instances where the Stock Number appears twice, to give me a query showing stock currently held.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Can you provide table structure (fields and types)? Why not normalize your data into separate tables for Purchased and Sold items using StockNumber as related key? Then you can compare both for current stock.

Comment: Access has a query wizard to find duplicate data in a table.

Comment: I think a little more explanation is needed.
The DB is in essence a electronic gun dealer database. Each gun has to be recorded in and then out of the register. Screenshot for the fields to give some idea of what I am doing.
Query will show the current stock held. 
Each gun is given a unique "Stock No." when entered on the register, but the same "Stock No" appears again when the gun is signed off the register.
I am trying to write a simple query which shows all the guns in the register with only one entry in the register (ie. received in).

Comment: Please don't add info as comment or answer. **Edit** your question and add the info there. Then you can delete the comment and the answer.

Comment: I apologize for my etiquette, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

That could be:

```
Select * From YourTable
Where ProductId In 
    (Select ProductId From YourTable 
    Group By ProductID
    Having Count(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions, I think a little more explanation is needed.
The DB is in essence a electronic gun dealer database. Each movement of a gun has to be recorded in and then out of the register. I have included a screenshot for the fields to give some idea of what I am doing.
I am trying to write a query which will show the current stock held. 
This has been complicated by the fact that each gun is given a unique "Stock No." when entered on the register, but the same "Stock No" appears again when the gun is signed off the register.
I am trying to write a simple query which shows all the guns in the register with only one entry in the register (ie. received in).

This is not about removing duplicates from the DB.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCceA.jpg)

Comment: That's exactly what my query will do. You should, however, use the _serial number_ which, I assume, must be unique across all firearms/pieces.

Comment: The serial number would not be unique, a firearm could be bought and sold numerous times by the same dealer. The stock no is however only used the once. Could you elaborate a bit more on your coding for me, I keep getting a syntax error which I cant resolve. Many Thanks

Comment: It simply finds all Ids that appear once only, then filters the base table on these Ids. Code is tested here, so you probably have a field name with a space or a typo.

Comment: I cannot see where I am going wrong with this repeated syntax error. I am a newbie self taught in access, and usually work in the design view, SELECT *[Main Database].[Stock Ref No]
Where [Main Database].[Stock Ref No] In
(SELECT [Main Database].[Stock Ref No]
GROUP BY [Main Database].[Stock Ref No]
HAVING Count (*)=1)

Comment: Really? Read again (_Hint:_ From).

Comment: Gustav Thank you, I think I am getting somewhere. I was including other fields in my query not just Stock Ref. Once I realised that....couldn't have got there without your help